# 14.04 Files slow and freezing

Tags: 14.04, files

I'm running a fully updated 14.04 system and I keep getting long delays when performing certain tasks with the "Files" application.  Sometimes deleting files will take upwards of a couple minutes to start, with the Files grinding to a halt and going grey.  The rest of the computer is fine.  Going to the terminal ans rm'ing (if I can verb that) has no delay.  Sometimes opening a new window will have this same delay as well.  I've tried different desktops (gnome, kde) using their respective file browsers and have not had any issues.

I don't think this is an issue with the computer itself, is there something I need to configure with Files to get rid of this?

Here's my system:

Processor       : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Memory          : 16343MB (2822MB used)

OS              : Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

1TB 7200RPM Disk

256GB SSD for OS

Cheers,

Fratink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Deleting files in Nautilus aka Files uses a lot more resources than a simple `rm` command. One reason is the use of so-called Recycle Bin, the files are only moved, and this trash has to be managed by the system. This takes time and resources
2. You've certainly run a service that indexes files. So if there are changes in the filesystem, then runs this service to update its databases. Even this takes time and resources.

I contend that the hard disk is just too slowly or improperly integrated into your system. 7200 RPM alone says nothing . Your SSD is certainly fast enough.

Check your both drives with

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdb
```

and watch the IO rate with

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
sudo iotop
```

and read [this](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Tune-Your-Hard-Disk-with-hdparm) for some optimizations.

---

*Some examples from [this](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Tune-Your-Hard-Disk-with-hdparm) source:*

1. The Linux kernel deposits the data retrieved from the hard drive into a buffer. To determine the speed of the unadorned drive, you can use the

   ```
   hdparm -t --direct /dev/sda
   ```
2. Some drive properties can be changed while the device is in operation; for example, most drives allow you to turn power management on and off. Just which functions hdparm can change and activate on a hard drive can be called up with

   ```
   hdparm -I /dev/sda
   ```

   and are found under Commands/features (Figure 1). All functions found there and marked with an asterisk are currently active, and hdparm can use the rest or at least activate them.

   To speed up data transmission, a hard disk usually reads several sectors at the same time. How many it can deliver at the same time is revealed by

   ```
   hdparm -I /dev/sda
   ```

   and is listed after R/W multiple sector transfer: Max =. This value should also be found in the same line after Current =. If that is not the case, you can increase the value with:

   ```
   hdparm -m16 /dev/sda
   ```

   This instructs the hard drive always to deliver 16 sectors at once.

   Curiously, some hard drives run slower with higher values: The hdparm man page mentions primarily older Caviar drives from Western Digital. In such cases, you should reduce the number of sectors again or even turn the function off completely, which is done with:

   ```
   hdparm -m0 /dev/sda
   ```

   Beyond this, modern drives can even retrieve a few sectors in advance (“read ahead”). To define how many, use the -a switch (Figure 4, top) – for example:

   ```
   hdparm -a256 /dev/sda
   ```

   Here, the drive will read the 256 sectors in advance that are most likely the next to be requested. Higher values speed up above all the reading of large files – at the cost, however, that reading smaller ones takes longer. The current setting is shown with

   ```
   hdparm -a /dev/sda
   ```

   Beyond that, many drives also possess a built-in, additional read-ahead function. As a rule, therefore, you can leave the setting at the default value.

   How fast queries from the operating system reach the hard drive controller can be called up with

   hdparm -c /dev/sda

   The value should be 32-bit; you can force this value with the -c3 switch.
3. Many modern hard drives allow you to slow down the head movement. Although doing so will increase access times, it will also reduce the noise level. To find out whether your own hard drive offers this “acoustic mode,” you can use this command:

   ```
   hdparm -M /dev/sda
   ```

   If a number follows the equal sign, as shown in Figure 4 (bottom), the drive can be put into a quiet mode with:

   ```
   hdparm -M 128 /dev/sda
   ```

   To reach the highest speed, use the maximum value:

   ```
   hdparm -M 254 /dev/sda
   ```

   Values between 128 and 254 are allowed, resulting in a trade-off between noise level and speed. Incidentally, your Linux kernel must also support acoustic management, which should be the case for all current major distributions.

   Some CD and DVD drives turn out to be more like turbines: Their high-speed rotation can hinder audio/video enjoyment. The

   ```
   hdparm -E 4 /dev/sr0
   ```

   command will provide relief. The parameter 4 determines speed, and /dev/sr0 specifies the DVD drive. This example slows drive reading speed ninefold.
4. With write-back caching, the hard drive first stores the data to be written in a buffer. In this way, it can accept data much faster, which in the end leads to a faster write speed. The

   hdparm -W /dev/sda

   command shows whether write-back caching is active with a 1 after the equals sign; otherwise, you can activate the function with the -W1 switch.

   If hdparm will not allow this change, you need to make sure that write-back caching has been activated in the BIOS. However, this function is not recommended for all situations: In the case of a power outage, the data in the buffer would be lost permanently.

   If a program sensitive to data loss – such as a database – is running on the system, you should turn off the write-back cache with the -W0 switch. Documentation for the PostgreSQL database even explicitly recommends that this be done.
5. If a hard disk or SSD doesn’t have anything to do for a certain period of time, it automatically enters sleep mode. This power-saving feature can be influenced with the -B parameter. Thus, using:

   hdparm -B255 /dev/sda

   would deactivate energy management; however, not all drives allow this.

   Instead of 255, values between 1 and 254 are allowed. A higher value means more power is used but also promises higher performance or speed. Values between 1 and 128 allow the drive to shut down, whereas values from 129 to 254 forbid that from happening.

   The most power can be saved with a value of 1; the highest rate of data transmission (I/O performance) is achieved with 254. You can call up the current value with:

   ```
   hdparm -B /dev/sda
   ```

   The specific effect the different values will have depends on the drive itself. However, you should keep in mind that too many shutdowns are not good for desktop hard drives: Each time it shuts off, the drive must park the heads, which increases wear and tear. Consequently, you shouldn’t wake your hard drive up every two seconds – which always takes more than two seconds to do.

   You can set how many seconds of idleness the hard drive should wait before it goes to sleep with the

   hdparm -S 128 /dev/sda

   switch; however, this value here is not in seconds but a number between 1 and 253. The hard drive multiplies this value by another. The value chosen in the example, 128, lies between 1 and 240, for which the drive uses a factor of five. Consequently, it would shut down after 640 seconds of idleness.

   From 241 and up, the multiplication factor increases steadily. At 251, the waiting period has increased to 5.5 hours. At 253, the value is preset by the manufacturer, usually between eight and 12 hours. The value 254 is left out; at 255, the drive will wait 21 minutes and 15 seconds. A value of 0 will deactivate sleep mode completely. To send the hard drive to sleep immediately, enter:

   ```
   hdparm -y /dev/sda
   ```

   With a capital Y, the drive will go into an even deeper state of sleep. Depending on the drive, the drive might only wake up from a deep sleep after a reset of the whole system.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the excellent explanation!  I'll read up on this and do some investigating, but I thought I'd just say thanks first!